# Wordpress SEO - all content on same page or separate posts for better ranking?

Tags: wordpress, seo, ranking

I have a website at http://www.hairdressersinleedscitycentre.co.uk which currently ranks about 15th in Google when the keyword 'hairdressers in leeds city centre' is searched for.

At the moment I have a home page (root level of my site) that displays a brief intro and an image. Then I have a page at http://hairdressersinleedscitycentre.co.uk/hairdressers-in-leeds-city-centre/ that lists all my posts (Probably a good idea to change the the alias here?).

All my posts link through to their own individual pages (about 50 posts in total), each of which Google indexes. Currently, about 45 or so of these are being omitted due to them having similar content in each.

So now to the question in hand; if I want to get my site ranked higher with the above keyword, would all my posts be better off  as - (a) All in one big single post/page or (b) As they are in separate posts but with better SEO optimization (META & alt tags etc...).

Answer (score 1):

Have one page for each topic you wish to discuss. This allows each page to be tailored to that topic by use of `<hx>` and other semantic markup (e.g. `<title>,`links). If you have similar content spread across multiple pages you should either condense all of that content on to one page or use canonical URLs to tell the search engines which page is the "main" page and to disregard the others (and thus prevent duplicate content/low quality content issues).

FYI, meta tags have no effect on a page's ranking and alt *attributes* have so little value that they're not even worth worrying about (but you should use them properly as they do increase the accessibility of your website).

Comment: Helpful reply, thanks for this. Most of my pages are similar at the moment but that may change eventually. So will probably all my posts separate.

Answer (score 1):

go back to basics. do your keyword research using google adwords keyword tool, collate the results in a spreadsheet and identify the head terms and long tail variations, then look at synonyms within google search - type ~yourkeyword into google (with the ~) and then collate these just like you did long tail, with the synonyms under each head term.

then create a unique title that starts with your main keyword and its long tail

the content should be between 300 and 600 words (the more the better) and be of magazine quality (not filler or rambling), make it really useful and take out your commercial intent i.e. dont try and sell anyting

make sure this content has bullet points and the appropriate headings

dont bother too much about keyword density but do think about adding in your synonym terms where appropriate

then adjust your website menu system to reflect these head terms

and build links to each page using a combination of all of the head, long tail and synonym terms as your anchor text from sites that have a high trustrank

hope that helps

Comment: That helps a lot actually, never thought about doing anything like that. Thanks man.

Answer (score 0):

Do both.

Every post should have its own page. These post pages can then be Search engine optimized for each post individually (like meta tags, title tag, user-friendly url, h1 tag for post title, ...).

For navigation and usability, you can still make a page with multiple post teasers listed. Pages like this are useful to navigate, but score less in search engines. Here you have the individual post pages for. Make sure that you give your post links on this page all relevant title-attributes.

Make sure that search engines are able to find the individual post pages. adding them to your sitemap will certainly help.

Using keywords in post titles and user-friendly urls tells search engines and your visitors a lot. Don't make the titles or urls too long or irrelevant.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Yeah that's how I've got my site set out at the moment, Google spiders are picking up all my pages but omitting most, due to the content being similar. Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Just to make things a bit easier for you, I'd suggest using this plugin - http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/wordpress-seo/

It adds another box to each page/post in the WP admin that will allow you to give unique titles, descriptions and keywords to each of your pages/posts.

There's a huge amount of benefits to using it but we've had great success with it.

Comment: I've already got tons of plugins like that, probably overkill with the amount I do actually have tbh... Not sure if some of my plugins may even be conflicting in turn confusing Google spiders... lol. Thanks anyway.

Comment: @luke it's more than likely that they are conflicting, probably best to stick to one.